# Timepicker inside table

Tags: css, angular, ngx-bootstrap

In my Angular app, I'm using the [timepicker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/timepicker) widget from [ngx-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap).

It looks fine when used outside a table:

[image]

However, for some reasons it looks super-ugly when used inside a `table` element:

[image]

I'm not using any custom css code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while to figure out what was happening there. The problem was some bootstrap style attached to `.table` and similar classes (e.g. rules applied to `.table td`) was breaking the timepicker's layout (since it internally also uses a `table` element).

My solution was applying this style:

```
timepicker {
  table {
    tr {
      background-color: transparent !important;

      th,
      td {
        padding: 0 !important;
        vertical-align: middle !important;
        border: none !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd love to know where to put this? For me, it's not working. I'm using .scss styles.

Comment: I got it to work. I needed to add it to the global `styles.scss` file. Thanks.